# Postgres trigger procedure seems to be memoized

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, plpgsql

I'm trying to create a trigger in postgresql to automatically to set some fields before insertion but my procedure to calculate the value is being called only once per session instead of on every insert. Here is how I'm trying to achieve this,

#### Create a test table

```
>> create table test (
    id varchar(16) unique not null
);
```

#### Try to insert into table without providing a value for `id`

```
>> insert into test DEFAULT VALUES;
ERROR:  null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
```

As expected, `id` cannot be `null`.

#### Create a function and trigger to automatically set `id` before insert.

```
>> create or replace function set_id() returns trigger language plpgsql as $$                                                             
begin                                                            
    new.id = gen_custom_unique_id();
    return new;
end $$;


>> CREATE TRIGGER client_update_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON test FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE set_id();
```

Where `gen_custom_unique_id` is another custom function.

Trying to insert rows into the table,

```
>> insert into test DEFAULT VALUES;
INSERT 0 1

>> select id from test;
    id
------------------
  0_EQOEatMNaXO2a-
(1 row)
```

.. which works as expected.

### The problem

#### Try to insert another row

```
>> insert into test DEFAULT VALUES;
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "test_id_key"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(0_EQOEatMNaXO2a-) already exists.
```

My understanding is that this should call the procedure `set_id` again and generate a new unique id but this only calls `set_id` once per session. `INSERT` works again if I disconnect from the database and try in a new session.

`EXECUTE PROCEDURE set_id();` does look suspicious as we are calling the procedure inline. Intuitively, I think it should be `EXECUTE PROCEDURE set_id;` and then the trigger should "call" `set_id` before every row is inserted but that doesn't work.

How do I turn `EXECUTE PROCEDURE set_id();` into something like `EXECUTE PROCEDURE lazy(set_id());`?

### Update

I'm sure `gen_custom_unique_id` is working properly. The code is too verbose and irrelevant to share here IMO. For the sake of this example, we can assume it just returns a UUID or the timestamp. I've tested that it works as expected, here is the output.

```
>> select * from gen_custom_unique_id();
   gen_custom_unique_id
------------------
 0_Elu4sdjRxW6s_s
(1 row)

>> select * from gen_custom_unique_id();
   gen_custom_unique_id
------------------
 0_EluVMKwLjJQP2s
(1 row)

>> select * from gen_custom_unique_id();
   gen_custom_unique_id
------------------
 0_ElutuejkWhR07N
(1 row)

>> select * from gen_custom_unique_id();
   gen_custom_unique_id
------------------
 0_ElvHrif6X2pQH-
(1 row)

>> select * from gen_custom_unique_id();
   gen_custom_unique_id
------------------
 0_ElvgXWgGIMYeHk
(1 row)
```

This function generates something like firebase or simpleflake IDs (http://akmanalp.com/simpleflake_presentation/#/)

### Update 2

I did some further tests and looks like the output of `get_custom_unique_id` or `set_id` is indeed cached.

I added a NOTICE statement to `get_custom_unique_id` and it is printed only the first time the function is called by the trigger.

#### Calling `gen_custom_unique_id` 3 times in a row

```
>> select * from gen_custom_unique_id();
NOTICE:  generating id: 0_Il_GKmrwCwkUJJ
   gen_custom_unique_id
------------------
 0_Il_GKmrwCwkUJJ
(1 row)

>> select * from gen_custom_unique_id();
NOTICE:  generating id: 0_Il_xBXWXvLuwBk
   gen_custom_unique_id
------------------
 0_Il_xBXWXvLuwBk
(1 row)

>> select * from gen_custom_unique_id();
NOTICE:  generating id: 0_IlbKk0ixgnkIdA
   gen_custom_unique_id
------------------
 0_IlbKk0ixgnkIdA
(1 row)
```

Notice how it prints `NOTICE: generating id: {generated_id}`.

#### Calling from the TRIGGER

```
>> insert into test DEFAULT VALUES;
NOTICE:  generating id: 0_IsgcquLRup1KxF
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT gen_custom_unique_id()"
PL/pgSQL function set_id() line 3 at assignment
INSERT 0 1

>> insert into test DEFAULT VALUES;
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "test_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(0_IsgcquLRup1KxF) already exists.
```

The notice from `gen_custom_unique_id` is printed only on first invocation so it definitely is not being called every time.

Comment: Is there any reason for *not* using a serial?

Comment: So what does `gen_custom_unique_id()` do?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It generates a unique ID using a custom algorithm. We can safely assume in this example that it returns a UUID, a timestamp or even a sequence.

Comment: `EXECUTE PROCEDURE set_id();` does not "call" the procedure. It merely "tells" the trigger to call that function when the trigger fires.

Comment: I would very much suspect that function to **not** generate a unique id properly. Show us that code. Neither a trigger nor a trigger function has any "state" that is preserved over multiple calls.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Right, but in my experience it doesn't work like that. May be then the issue is with the body of `set_id()` function.

Comment: Maybe it is even defined as `stable` instead of `volatile` (on line#42)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name updated question with some details about custom id generation

Comment: Could you use your custom generator function as a default value for id, in a similar way as how serials are implemented in postgres?

Comment: Does that function involve using `current_timestamp` (or `now()`)?  Are you aware that that returns the time at the **start of the transaction**? If it does use that, does your trigger work properly when using `clocktimestamp()`? If you did the two inserts in a single transaction that would explain why the second invocation returns the same id. But without the actual code this is impossible to tell. Neither the trigger nor the trigger function remembers any state. The only place where this can go wrong is your function to generate the id.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name With the same timestamp, the ID should be similar but not the same. The ID is a combination of the timestamp and `get_random_bytes()` from pgcrypto. Would `get_random_bytes` also return the same number in a single transaction?

Comment: I actually tried it in different transactions but from my application. May be my usage of transactions was wrong. I'll test it again later today and report back.

Comment: Again: please show us the code of `gen_custom_unique_id()` there is most definitely something strange going on in there.

Comment: @wildplasser Thanks! You set me on the right course. The `get_custom_unique_id` was an IMMUTABLE function and not VOLATILE.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm not sure if I've the rights to share the code for that func or I'd have already but that is where the issue was. It was defined as an IMMUTABLE function instead of VOLATILE.

Thanks!

Comment: @wildplasser I'd be happy to accept an answer if you post it.

Comment: Ok. I added as a comment. Remember: the snippet was only a proof-of-concept, and we didn't know your *secret* function ...

Comment: I know! It was not a good question but unfortunately I was not sure if I was authorized to publicly share all parts :(

Answer (score 0):

For your information: hooking up a (call to a) *custom* function as a default value for a column can be done in just the same way as how serials are implemented in postgres. It doesn't need a trigger. I demonstrate with clock_timestamp() as a *sequence-generating* function:

```
CREATE TABLE omg
              -- NOTE: clock_timestamp is volatile by nature,
              -- which means that the query-optimiser cannot presume
              -- that calling it twice would result in the same result
              -- (THUS: the function is called anytime a value is needed)
    ( id timestamp NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT clock_timestamp()
    , payload text
    );

INSERT INTO omg(payload) VALUES ('one' );
INSERT INTO omg(payload) VALUES ('two' );
SELECT * FROM omg;
```

---

Result:

```
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 1
INSERT 0 1
             id             | payload 
----------------------------+---------
 2015-11-11 15:29:07.330905 | one
 2015-11-11 15:29:07.338803 | two
(2 rows)
```

Comment: I actually tried this but it did not work the way I expected it to. I can't  remember what the exact issue was though. Will try it again later

Comment: The issue with this approach was that I don't have control over the application and the application always sends down default a value (null or '') to the database which doesn't let postgres execute it's own.

Comment: Kill the application. (or disallow it to connect, for a start ;-)